# How to Filter Data from JSON API

Tags: java, android, json, api, filtering

I only want to display the "Lucky 7 Classic" data based on "theme_name".
Here's my Call function.

```
public MutableLiveData<List<PrizesModel>> getPrize(){
    final MutableLiveData<List<PrizesModel>> pData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    Call<List<PrizesModel>> call = rfit.retrofitBuilderPrize().getPrizes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PrizesModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PrizesModel>> call, Response<List<PrizesModel>> response) {
            try {
                List<PrizesModel> pList = response.body();
                for (int i = 0; i < pList.size()-1; i++){
                    if (pList.get(i).getThemeName().equals("Lucky 7 Classic")){
                        pData.setValue(pList);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PrizesModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                pData.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    return pData;
}
```

I'm using MVVM Structure on this project and Retrofit2.

And this is the JSON Response i  want to filter based on theme_name.

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "theme_name": "Lucky 7 Classic",
    "choose": "SỐ 7",
    "first_coin": "1000",
    "second_coin": "2000",
    "third_coin": "5000",
    "theme_image": ""
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "theme_name": "Lucky 7 Classic",
    "choose": "SỐ 7 MAY MẮN",
    "first_coin": "250",
    "second_coin": "500",
    "third_coin": "750",
    "theme_image": ""
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "theme_name": "Lucky 7 Ocean",
    "choose": "Ba con cá bướm",
    "first_coin": "300",
    "second_coin": "600",
    "third_coin": "900",
    "theme_image": ""
},
{
    "id": 21,
    "theme_name": "Lucky 7 Ocean",
    "choose": "Ba con Cá hề",
    "first_coin": "250",
    "second_coin": "500",
    "third_coin": "750",
    "theme_image": ""
}
```

It displays all the data from the API instead of the desired value

Comment: You already are applying a filter. What's the problem? What doesn't work? Note that `catch(Exception e) {}` - empty catch blocks are a big No-No. You should handle it properly, i.e. if nothing else then at least log it.

Comment: @Thomas it still not taking effect.. it still displaying all the data from the Api

Comment: Ah, I see it now: `pData.setValue(pList);` - don't do that. You're basically returning the entire list if you have a match. Instead you need a second list that only receives the matching elements. You could do that with streams but I'd suggest you try it the "traditional" way first (create an empty list, add matching elements and after the loop you call `pData.setValue(yourNewList)`).